# Is there a way to use Altair selection to highlight one field based on another?

Tags: python-3.x, altair

I'm using altair interactive charts to display clusters of genes and I want to add a feature where a user can select a specific gene, and highlight it's entire cluster. I am using the following code to create two charts of gene clusters. I already have a selection that can either filter the charts by gene or by cluster, but I would like to be able to select the gene in the selection, but have the charts filtered based on the cluster of the gene, rather than the name of the gene.

For example, if gene A is in cluster 42, I would like to select 'gene A' in a dropdown menu and have that pass '42' to a selection object, which is then used to filter the chart.

```
input_dropdown = alt.binding_select(options=list(pd.unique(df_samp['CGI'])), name='gene')
selection = alt.selection_single(fields=['CGI'], bind = input_dropdown)

#Create UMAP scatter plot
UMAP_chart = alt.Chart(df_samp).mark_circle(size=6).encode(
    x='UMAP_1',
    y='UMAP_2',
    color = alt.Color('UPGMA_label:N', legend = None),
    opacity=alt.condition(selection, alt.value(1.0), alt.value(0.0))                         
).properties(height=500, width=500
).transform_filter(
    datum.UPGMA_label == 
)

#Create pattern line plot
graph_cols = ['CGI', 'week0', 'week1', 'week2', 'week4', 'week6', 'week8', 'UPGMA_label']
graph_df = df_samp[graph_cols].melt(['CGI', 'UPGMA_label'], var_name='week', value_name='data')

pattern_chart = alt.Chart(graph_df).mark_line().encode(
    x='week',
    y='data',
    color= alt.Color('CGI:N', legend = None),
    opacity=alt.condition(selection, alt.value(1.0), alt.value(0.0)) 
).properties(width=500)

chart = alt.hconcat(pattern_chart, UMAP_chart).add_selection(selection)
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your dataset that can be used to run the code above? Or create a minimal reproducible example using one of the vega sample data sets from the documentation?

Comment: @joelostblom
Here is a link to the data head: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1csR4Hwkupv1aou0JzJ1L9NSth8bJ338-/view?usp=sharing)

Use this line to get the graph_cols variable: graph_cols = ['CGI', 'week0', 'week1', 'week2', 'week4', 'week6', 'week8', 'UPGMA_label']

Essentially, I want to be able to select a CGI value in the selector, but have the graph filtered based on the UPGMA_label of the given CGI.

Comment: Thanks, I tried a bit but couldn't find a way to achieve what you want. You might consider another approach such as having the gene name visible in the tooltip but the box select on the cluster only. You could also try creating a simplified example using the build in data set, open it in the vega editor, and re-ask the question as a vega lite question instead.